# Shuffle on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I have a question how can i shuffle this one within an array? please kindly help me. i would really appreciate you help guys thank you so much!

What im trying to do is shuffle this one within an array.

```
    // ______________________________________________Function to declare our var -> deck of cards

function getDeck() {

    var deck = [
        {suit: "H", face: "A"},
        {suit: "H", face: "2"},
        {suit: "H", face: "3"},
        {suit: "H", face: "4"},
        {suit: "H", face: "5"},
        {suit: "H", face: "6"},
        {suit: "H", face: "7"},
        {suit: "H", face: "8"},
        {suit: "H", face: "9"},
        {suit: "H", face: "10"},
        {suit: "H", face: "J"},
        {suit: "H", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "H", face: "K"},
        {suit: "C", face: "A"},
        {suit: "C", face: "2"},
        {suit: "C", face: "3"},
        {suit: "C", face: "4"},
        {suit: "C", face: "5"},
        {suit: "C", face: "6"},
        {suit: "C", face: "7"},
        {suit: "C", face: "8"},
        {suit: "C", face: "9"},
        {suit: "C", face: "10"},
        {suit: "C", face: "J"},
        {suit: "C", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "C", face: "K"},
        {suit: "D", face: "A"},
        {suit: "D", face: "2"},
        {suit: "D", face: "3"},
        {suit: "D", face: "4"},
        {suit: "D", face: "5"},
        {suit: "D", face: "6"},
        {suit: "D", face: "7"},
        {suit: "D", face: "8"},
        {suit: "D", face: "9"},
        {suit: "D", face: "10"},
        {suit: "D", face: "J"},
        {suit: "D", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "D", face: "K"},
        {suit: "S", face: "A"},
        {suit: "S", face: "2"},
        {suit: "S", face: "3"},
        {suit: "S", face: "4"},
        {suit: "S", face: "5"},
        {suit: "S", face: "6"},
        {suit: "S", face: "7"},
        {suit: "S", face: "8"},
        {suit: "S", face: "9"},
        {suit: "S", face: "10"},
        {suit: "S", face: "J"},
        {suit: "S", face: "Q"},
        {suit: "S", face: "K"},
    ];

    return deck;
}

// ______________________________________________Function to shuffle cards

function shuffle(o) { // o is passed-in array

     for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i, 10), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
     return o;

};
```

Here's the other code and i think here lies the problem or no? :

```
// ______________________________________________Function to retrieve our deck of cards & save into localStorage

function getShoe(decks) {

    var shoe = [];
    var deck = getDeck();
    this.decks = decks;

        for (z=1;z<=decks;z++) {
            shoe.push(deck);
        }

    shoe = shuffle(shoe);
    return shoe;


    localStorage.setItem('shoe', JSON.stringify(shoe));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your shuffle function:

```
o.sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()})
```

From http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml

Comment: Deck still not shuffled.

Comment: Interesting. Do you get any errors, or does nothing happen?

Comment: This is a bad way to shuffle. My post here covers these concepts in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557911/shuffle-using-icomparer In a nutshell: it's prone to failure because given three items (a,b, and c) in a larger list, at various points during the shuffle it may compare such that a > b, b > c, and c > a. Even if that weren't true, this method is prone to bias.

Comment: Is there any guys to make this one work?

Comment: @user2910182 Check the link in the comment to your question.