# Select any random string from a list

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

How can I select any random string from a given list of strings? Example:

```
List1: banana, apple, pineapple, mango, dragon-fruit
List2: 10.2.0.212, 10.4.0.221, 10.2.0.223
```

When I call some function like **randomize(List1) = somevar** then it will just take any string from that particular list. The result in **somevar** will be totally random. How can it be done? Thank you very much :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to randomize a list in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554587/is-there-an-easy-way-to-randomize-a-list-in-vb-net)

Comment: It seems so compilcated. But I'll try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

```
Dim rnd = new Random()
Dim randomFruit = List1(rnd.Next(0, List1.Count))
```

Note that you have to reuse the random instance if you want to execute this code in a loop. Otherwise the values would be repeating since random is initialized with the current timestamp.

So this works:

```
Dim rnd = new Random()
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Dim randomFruit = List1(rnd.Next(0, List1.Count))
    Console.WriteLine(randomFruit)
Next
```

since always the same random instance  is used.

But this won't work:

```
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Dim rnd = new Random()
    Dim randomFruit = List1(rnd.Next(0, List1.Count))
    Console.WriteLine(randomFruit)
Next
```

Comment: Much thanks, you're a live saver! This is my code:         Dim rnd = New Random()
        Dim availServers(0 To 2) As String

        availServers(0) = "Deftones"
        availServers(1) = "Tool"
        availServers(2) = "Disturbed". Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`List` of `String`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). 
Create a random number generator: [Random class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
Call Random number generator's `NextInt()` method with `List.Count` as the upper bound.
Return `List[NextInt(List.count)]`.
Job done :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate a random number between 1 and the size of the list, and use that as an index?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. Maybe the OP is new to this, and wants some code examples (as posted by others)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function randomize(ByVal lst As ICollection) As Object
    Dim rdm As New Random()
    Dim auxLst As New List(Of Object)(lst)
    Return auxLst(rdm.Next(0, lst.Count))
End Function
```

Or just for string lists:

```
Public Function randomize(ByVal lst As ICollection(Of String)) As String
    Dim rdm As New Random()
    Dim auxLst As New List(Of String)(lst)
    Return auxLst(rdm.Next(0, lst.Count))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, this is a simple loop to pick every item from a list, but in a random manner:

```
Dim Rand As New Random
For C = 0 to LIST.Count - 1 'Replace LIST with the collection name
    Dim RandomItem As STRING = LIST(Rand.Next(0, LIST.Count - 1)) 'Change the item type if needed (STRING)

    '' YOUR CODE HERE TO USE THE VARIABLE NewItem ''

Next
```