# Referencing text from a 1D array for use in a line of code (vb)

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a small project, and one of the components utilizes an animated dice. I've got the mechanics of the dice down, however, I wish to make the dice colour change each time it rolls.

As of now, I have to manually set the colour
(e.g. `pnl1.Backcolor = system.Drawing.color.Red`).

I've already set up an array with the various different colours and intend to reference them randomly using the random number function, but my question is how can I refer to an item in the array in such a way that that makes the above mentioned `pnl1.Backcolor` match said colour?

I'm well aware I can't just use `system.Drawing.color.Colours(1)`, so how might I go about this/what are some possible alternate options to an array?

Any and all help is massively appreciated and I do apologise if the way I've formatted this question is not in line with that which the website demands (I'm relatively new).

Thanks,

~ John

Comment: Is the array strictly typed as colors? Or as a string representing the color? This may be far easier for you with a `List (of ...)` instead of array.

Comment: Check this thread for an example of what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15069799/7948962

Comment: I may consider that, but how may I implement that in to the above code? Thanks for the response!

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306394/randomize-3-colors/50306855#50306855), posted a few days ago. See if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you have a different panel for each side of the die or just one with a picture change, nevertheless, below is an example of something you could do. Change as needed (I'm assuming just one panel with color change - pnl1).

```
Dim PanColor() As Color = {Color.White, Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Purple, Color.Yellow}
    pnl1.BackColor = PanColor(put_random_number_here_0_to_5)
```

Comment: As much as I appreciate the help, the syntax for changing the panel colour doesn't seem to coincide with that which you've included in the above code. For example, I can't dim something as a color, only console colour.

Comment: The above assumes you have: Imports System.Drawing, if not, add 'System.Drawing' to each 'color'.