# Loop through all elements of an array in random order?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, loops, random

I have an 1 dimensional array with 24 elements inside it. I want to loop through all of them in random order. I know how to loop them from 1 - 24, but how to randomly select one and then another and so on until all elements have been selected?

I'm using a VB-like scripting language (QAWizard), so I think any idea or VB code will be enough.

Comment: I *think* you are looking for a shuffle. Looping in random order wont assure that one comes up only once (which I assume is essential if "QA" implies a quiz of some sort).

Comment: @Plutonix I think the QA in QA Wizard stands for Quality Assurance. It seems to be an aid for testing software. It doesn't seem to be a .Net language, so I'm not convinced that the OP's assertion that "any idea or VB code will be enough" is correct..

Comment: @Blackwood Could be - there are a lot of quiz game questions that get posted from time to time.  Not a lot of context given. OP: If thats the case, a proper shuffle might be better.  Easier to document/assure about un biased results.

Comment: Create a list of the indexes, shuffle it, iterate through it to index into your array. Your original list is untouched - it might be expensive to shuffle that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,@plutonix, @Blackwood, @Andrew Morton.  The QA (Quality Assurance ) Wizard is a auto test tool, for software test purpose, it is a scripting language similar to VB, not a quiz game lol, my fault. Problem is that it doesn`t have lots of build-in functions like shuffle, it supports basic loop, condition, JSON, So, I don`t know how to do if you just  give me a "Shuffle",  if I can see some logic then I will write some built-in function and transfer it to the language. So can you please be more specific about that shuffle? Thanks ,@plutonix, @Blackwood, @Andrew Mor

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's `OrderBy` and [`Random.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b3ta19y(v=vs.110).aspx) to order it randomly:

```
Private Shared _rnd As New Random

Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    Dim arr As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    For Each value In arr.OrderBy(Function(x) _rnd.Next())
        Debug.WriteLine(value)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Random` might be better than `Guid.NewGuid` but OP has to remember to not use a local variable. Your `Shared` approach is fine until the app starts to be multithreaded. Then you need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19271062/284240) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TimSchmeiter,  can you please elaborate the part: "(Function(x)_rnd.next())" ? The QA(quality assurance) Wizard, doesn`t have the build-in function like that, I need to write it myself. so I`d appreciate it if you can help with that  thx

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
Dim randomOrder = From item In yourArray Order By Guid.NewGuid()

For Each item In randomOrder

Next
```

The `Guid` trick is not the best way to "randomize" a collection, have a look at a shuffle approach like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7513502/284240